# How to thread over ragged list while skipping empty sub-lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a very large ragged list result that is a list of list of pairs where sometimes the sub-list contains the empty list.

```
res = {{{20, 1}, {200, 2}}, {{}}, {{175, 1}}};
```

In the above minimal example there are 3 list with 2 containing list of pairs and one the empty list. The actual list is much longer with longer sub-list.

I need to place a value from `RandomVariate` as the third entry in each pair.  However, to keep performance reasonable, I only want to call `RandomVariate` once for the total number of values I need.  In this case I would call it for 3 values.

If the 3 values returned are

```
vals = {a, b, c};
```

Then is it possible to efficiently produce

```
{{{20, 1, a}, {200, 2, b}}, {{}}, {{175, 1, c}}}
```

without loops/procedural programming? For context the actual list will hold around 100,000+ sub-list each with zero to five pairs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, vals_] := Module[{n = 0}, Replace[x, y_ /; y != {} :> Append[y, vals[[++n]]], {-2}]]
```

Example:

```
res = {{{20, 1}, {200, 2}}, {{}}, {{175, 1}}};
vals = {a, b, c};

f[res, vals]
```

> {{{20, 1, a}, {200, 2, b}}, {{}}, {{175, 1, c}}}

Comment: `Block` with `PreIncrement` and that negative `Replace` level spec. You are too clever! (1+) while we wait.

Comment: @Edmund, thank you for the vote. I am sure I  learned the trick  somewhere on this site:)

Comment: I was "chastised" once by @Mr.Wizard about using `Block` instead of `Module` in this construction, because there's some weird unexpected "psuedo-leakiness" in `Block`.  I can't remember exactly what the issue is, though.

Comment: @march, being "chastised"... it does ring a bell:)

Comment: @march Evaluating `f[res, {n, b, c}]` reveals the problem.  `Module` will fix it.  Still +1, though.

Comment: @WReach, thank you; changed to `Module`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map[Replace[{x_, y_} :> {x, y, RandomReal[]}], res, {2}]
```

**Edit** (to make all rvs at once):

```
res = {{{20, 1}, {200, 2}}, {{}}, {{175, 1}}};
n = 2*Length[res]
rvs = RandomReal[1, n]
i = 1
Map[Replace[{x_, y_} :> {x, y, rvs[[i++]]}], res, {2}]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I only want to call `RandomVariate` once.

Comment: @Edmund Ah, I misunderstood what you meant by that.  How will you know how many values you need?

Comment: By the number of pairs in the list.

Comment: @Edmund See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)

```
n = 0;
f[{}] = {};
f[x_] := Append[x, vals[[++n]]]
Outer[f, res, 2]
```

> {{{20, 1, a}, {200, 2, b}}, {{}}, {{175, 1, c}}}

Answer (score 2):

```
With[{pos = Position[res, {_Integer, _Integer}]}, 
 ReplacePart[res, 
  Thread[Rule[pos, MapThread[Append, {Extract[res, pos], vals}]]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Module[{i = 1}, res /. {a__?NumberQ} :> {Splice[{a}], vals[[i++]]}]
```

{{{20, 1, a}, {200, 2, b}}, {{}}, {{175, 1, c}}}